# CSGO suddenly cant join any servers

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

I cannot join any CSGO official servers since monday.

I can join any unofficial servers. I can go surfing and play on faceit but cant warm up in deathmatch or arms race.

I get this error code

```
No ping data available.
Unable to communicate with ANY of 45 Steam Datagram routing cluster.  Possible problem with local internet connection?
RelayNetWorkStatus:  avail=Failed  config=OK  anyrelay=Failed   (Unable to communicate with ANY of 45 Steam Datagram routing cluster.  Possible problem with local internet connection?)

[#1160826438 SDR server steamid:90140379019670538(vport 0)] problem detected locally (3002): Cannot talk to any relays. Check Internet connection
Steam Net connection #1160826438 SDR server steamid:90140379019670538(vport 0) problem detected locally, reason 3002: Cannot talk to any relays. Check Internet connection
**** Unable to localize '#GenericConfirmText_Label' on panel descendant of 'PopupManager'
Closing Steam Net Connection to (unknown), handle 4530ce46 (2001 Matchmaking failed.  We never heard from gameserver)
Summary of connection to #1160826438 SDR server steamid:90140379019670538(vport 0):
Router network: Failed
End-to-end connection: closed due to problem detected locally, reason code 3002.  (Cannot talk to any relays. Check Internet connection)
    Remote host is in data center 'iad'
```

found a few answers on steam community discussions but none helped me:

verified file integrity: check

reinstalled csgo: check

lauched steam with -tcp: check

the only thing i cannot do is lower the firewall settings on my router since im in college and the router belongs to the boarding house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The college possibly blocked the Steam matchmaking servers.
The only solution for that is a VPN.
It may also be an issue with the internet itself, referenced by the log.
In all cases, try a different connection and see if that fixes it

Comment: Might not be the only solution, depends how they were blocked. For example if it's via DNS you can put the IP-domain pairs in your local hosts file. In any case TCPview (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) would tell you which URLs are being connected to, then you can use ping or winmtr to test each connection.

Comment: I have tried via a vpn it works just fine, but with the cost of lags from time to time. CSGO directly connects to the IP adress of official servers. it doesnt need a DNS to request the IPs so changing the DNS didnt fix the problem.